# Install gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I have a problem 
when i want to install gnome-tweak-tool in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell-common iio-sensor-proxy mutter-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell-common gnome-tweak-tool iio-sensor-proxy mutter-common
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 633 kB/1,949 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 gnome-shell-common all 3.18.4-0ubuntu3 [609 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 iio-sensor-proxy amd64 1.1-1
  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Fetched 609 kB in 5s (111 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-proxy_1.1-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I did  `--fix-missing`  but nothing work ...

Comment: Simply try again. You have had an intermittent internet problem. The "Bad URI" mentioned in the error is correct and the file exists.

Comment: i tried a lot of time but there is no hope

Comment: Can you `ping archive.ubuntu.com`? Can you do `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-proxy_1.1-1_amd64.deb`? If yes, then the install should work. If not, you still have a network problem.

Comment: yes i can ping to this 

ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from steelix.canonical.com (91.189.88.152): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=84.7 ms

Comment: wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-pro‌​xy_1.1-1_amd64.deb
--2016-07-28 23:27:18--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-pro%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bxy_1.1-1_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.161, 91.189.88.162, 91.189.88.149, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad URI
2016-07-28 23:27:19 ERROR 400: Bad URI.

Comment: in software and update 
there is message said 

W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor64/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor64/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try 'sudo apt-get update' like the error message suggests?

Answer (score 12):

First, we need to enable universe repository. To do this, open Software and Update via application menu. Mark all universe repositories from the repo list.

[image: software and updates]

Click Reload to update Ubuntu.
Next, use the following command to install Gnome Tweak Tool

```
 sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Output:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 gnome-tweak-tool
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 435 not upgraded.
Need to get 205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,198 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 gnome-tweak-tool all 3.26.2.1-1ubuntu1 [205 kB]
Fetched 205 kB in 1s (106 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-tweak-tool.
(Reading database ... 145771 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-tweak-tool_3.26.2.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-tweak-tool (3.26.2.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up gnome-tweak-tool (3.26.2.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
```

Now run Gnome Tweak Tool

Comment: Run 'gnome-tweaks' to start. Seems to provide some options for the touchpad on minimal distros like Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Could be solved with a single command if you are facing this issue just after fresh install

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type this command and enter your password.

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by testing a lot of ways

1. In terminal

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Open this website https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/
   generate your Sources List
3. Paste it in terminal
4. type in terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Unfortunately in some countries you can't update or upgrade until you change to another source

This is what im figure out.

Is it right or not i don't know but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `gone-tweaks-tool` has been renamed to `gnome-tweaks`:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/gnome-tweak-tool-renamed-gnome-tweaks

To install it run:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`