# Problem with Super + Grave global shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, dconf, yakuake, tilda

My goal: open Yakuake or Tilda terminal with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Grave</kbd> (backtick, tilde, `) shortcut in Gnome.
What I could achieve is only holding Super + pressing Grave twice.

A little background. By default <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Grave</kbd> is a shortcut for `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-group`
So I disabled it in DConf editor.

Then when I just press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Grave</kbd> (<kbd>`</kbd>) once, I just see `` ` `` symbol in Tilda, while Yakuake shows `` s` `` somehow (yes, with additional s letter). But pressing Grave twice works (though additional `` ` `` symbol gets typed, that is annoying).

What's interesting, when I install *Drop Down Terminal* Gnome Extension and set <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Grave</kbd> shortcut it works perfectly. But *Drop Down Terminal* is too simple for me.

I use Gnome 3.32 and International English layout + Russian keyboard layout.

Comment: @DKBose Pardon me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @DKBose No, I literally use 19.10. It's gonna be realesed this Thursday, but it is already available for download. But this is not very important as I faced this issue in Linux Mint 19.1 which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: 19.04  will release this Thursday and not 19.10.. please change as @DKBose mentioned..

Comment: @dessert and DKBose sorry, my mistake, it is really 19.04. Edited the question.

Comment: @dessert you're not wrong, but the problem is actually distro agnostic. It's an issue with the keyboard settings and I have seen exactly the same problem running Cinnamon on Arch, so it isn't a problem about the development version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy to fix. You need to get the [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://askubuntu.com/a/968630/85695) and navigate to the keyboard settings. On Cinnamon, you can do the same by opening  Settings->keyboard->Layouts->Options. You should see something like this:

[image: Keyboard settings screenshot]

Open the "Alt/Win key behavior" and change it from "Default" to "Hyper is mapped to Win":

[image: Screenshot showing "hyper is mapped to win" selected]

That should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Fantastic! 
For future readers: "Keyboard Layout Options" window may be opened only from "Gnome Tweak Tool" app rather then "normal" Settings app (Starting from Ubuntu 13.10, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/360378/how-to-access-the-keyboard-layout-options-in-13-10)

Comment: Though, it brought another issue. Now somehow "Activity overview" of Gnome stopped working with default single pressing "Super" key shortcut. Temporarily added another shortcut.

Comment: @AlexeyChernov yes, that makes sense. As I understand it, the Hyper key (which you just mapped to the Win key) only works as a modifier of other keys for multi-key shortcuts. So if your Win is mapped to Hyper, you can no longer use Win alone as a shortcut key. And thanks for clarifying the settings, I use Cinnamon and assumed the path to the settings would be the same for Gnome.

Comment: Can I upvote this a thousand times?

Comment: Is it possible to keep default 'Win' shortcut?